# How to make the left div scroll position follow the window scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

To prevent the year on the left from showing too long, I limited his height. When I scroll the window, the content of the div on the left does not change.

I want to scroll the window, the content of the left div will automatically scroll to the appropriate year position. How can I make it follow the scroll position of the window to the appropriate year?

[jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sylc0619/zuhv8kL7/13/)

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var sections = $('.timeline_article'),
    nav = $('.scroll_navigation_section'),
    header_height = $('.header').outerHeight(),
    cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - header_height,
      bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.vertical_timeline_section {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll_navigation_section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.scroll_navigation_section .scroll_navigation_year {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.scroll_navigation_section .scroll_navigation_year li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.scroll_navigation_section .scroll_navigation_year li>a.active {
  color:red;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="btn1">Header btn1</a></li>
    <li><a href="btn2">Header btn2</a></li>
    <li><a href="btn3">Header btn3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section class="vertical_timeline_section">
  <section class="scroll_navigation_section">
    <div class="scroll_navigation_year">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#1964">1964</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1984">1984</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2000">2000</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2002">2002</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2009">2009</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2012">2012</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2015">2015</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2016">2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2019">2019</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2020">2020</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2021">2021</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2023">2023</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2025">2025</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="timeline_section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="timeline_article" id="1964">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">1964</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="1984">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">1984</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2000">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2002">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2002</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2009">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2009</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2012">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2012</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2015">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2016">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2016</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="timeline_article" id="2019">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: do you want to scroll with the mouse wheel and get into the corresponding block?

Comment: No. But someone solved my problem thanks. =v=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scrollIntoView` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

like this:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var sections = $('.timeline_article'),
    nav = $('.scroll_navigation_section'),
    header_height = $('.header').outerHeight(),
    cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - header_height,
      bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var aElement = nav.find('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]')
      aElement.addClass('active');
      if(aElement && $(aElement) && $(aElement)[0]){
        $(aElement)[0].scrollIntoView();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.vertical_timeline_section {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll_navigation_section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.scroll_navigation_section .scroll_navigation_year {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.scroll_navigation_section .scroll_navigation_year li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.scroll_navigation_section .scroll_navigation_year li>a.active {
  color:red;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="btn1">Header btn1</a></li>
    <li><a href="btn2">Header btn2</a></li>
    <li><a href="btn3">Header btn3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section class="vertical_timeline_section">
  <section class="scroll_navigation_section">
    <div class="scroll_navigation_year">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#1964">1964</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1984">1984</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2000">2000</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2002">2002</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2009">2009</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2012">2012</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2015">2015</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2016">2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2019">2019</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2020">2020</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2021">2021</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2023">2023</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2025">2025</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="timeline_section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="timeline_article" id="1964">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">1964</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="1984">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">1984</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2000">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2002">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2002</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2009">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2009</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2012">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2012</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2015">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline_article" id="2016">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2016</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="timeline_article" id="2019">
        <div class="meta_date">
          <span class="year">2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_article">
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```